# How do I add an image to my quiz

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, debugging

I am using swift and xcode for a quiz app (first app) and I want to insert and image that corresponds with the question. This is what I have so far:

Array for images:

```
    var pictures: [UIImage] = [(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "americanmap")), (#imageLiteral(resourceName: "map")), (#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Thumbs_Up_Hand_Sign_Emoji_large"))]
```

Function that displays the image (it is inside the new question function):

```
    images = pictures[currentQuestion]
```

On this part I get an error message: "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type[UIImageView]"

By the way, images is an outlet of the image on the storyboard

Thank you!!

Comment: Provide the full function and declaration of `images`

Comment: What is the type of this `images` outlet?

Comment: How do I check?

Comment: pictures is array that have many image literal but what do currentQuestion have ? images = pictures[currentQuestion] -> images is uiimageView okay, Pictures is Array okay, currentQuestin maybe array of Questions but while passing a image to images images = pictures[currentQuestion] here you need to pass index like pictures[2],

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it! I changed the code from:

```
images = pictures[currentQuestion]
```

to:

```
images.image = pictures[currentQuestion]
```

which I think changed its type. Thank you guys so much for your help!!